# How to specify a type for a SQL-like query?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types

What follows is a pretty complicated object (in an object-oriented, imperative, typed language), which I would like to create a type for with some sort of type annotations. I am open to how it is done, just trying to see how to get fine-grained in the types we specify, as they are relations between far-reaching parts of the object structure.

The object to type is a query in JSON, that might look like this (basically a SQL query):

```
{
  select: [
    {
      name: 'user',
      select: [
        {
          name: 'company',
          select: [
            {
              name: 'name',
            },
            {
              name: 'location',
              select: [
                {
                  name: 'city'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: 'size'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  rule: {
    type: 'gte',
    left: 'user/company/size',
    right: 10
  },
  limit: 20,
  sort: [
    { path: 'user/company/name', dir: -1 }
  ]
}
```

So it will fetch list of objects like this in the end, for example:

```
[
  {
    user: {
      company: {
        name: 'Foo',
        location: {
          city: 'Sydney'
        },
        size: 20
      }
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Now, we have schemas for these types of objects:

```
type Company {
  field name: String;
  field location: Location;
  field size: Int;
}

type User {
  field company: Company;
}

type Location {
  field city: String;
}

// ...
```

Same with schemas for the query node types, but I won't list them all out.

The question is, how do you specify the type for the query so that it is a **valid query?**

A valid query is one where the **rule attributes** (left/right) and **sort attributes** (path) point to paths that are in the `select` portion of the query. And the `select` portion of the query must also only select fields for which our schema / type system has the appropriate types and fields.

So you can't do:

```
rule: {
  left: 'user/company/hello',
  right: 10
}
```

Because there is no property `hello` on the `company` property of the `User` type. Etc.

So basically, this just to me seems like a really complicated thing to try and type properly. What I've done now / so far is just say "rule can be of type rule-gt, rule-lt, etc." but that's it. Not that the `rule.left` must only dig into a valid path on the select node. Likewise, I would say for the `select` portion, that there is a "select node type", and it can have many children select nodes, to form a tree. But it doesn't say anything about matching types in the schema, and digging into fields/properties on those schema types.

If this is too involved of a question (I am not sure how complicated the answer might be), then what is the general approach I should take to add this level of typing to the system? What kind of types would they possibly be? If it is not too much though, it would be very helpful to see some made-up type annotations for some made-up type system, that would account for such digging into related objects, I can't see yet how that might look. The typing solution doesn't need to be complete, just looking for something to get the ball rolling and break the ice/fog.

I am asking because I am working on a custom programming language and am ready to try and write types for this, but not sure how complex it should be / will get, or really how to get that fine-grained. Any help would be appreciated. My current level of typing is very primitive and like I said, only covers the bare basics so far, no digging/complex relations/dependencies.

Thinking on this, I end up with something jumbled up and going nowhere like this:

```
s: Schema(User, Company, Location)
q: Query(s)

type Query<s: Schema> = q => {
  q.select[0] instanceof s.User
  q.select[0].select[0] instanceof s.Company
  q.select[0].select[0].select[0] instanceof s.Location
  q.role.left[0] pointsto s.User
  q.role.left[0][0] pointsto s.User.company
  ...
}
```

Granted, I am no Haskell / functional language / type theory expert, so I am going to be pretty far off. But I would think I could at least figure out *some sort of way* to model the system, yet I am drawing a blank currently. And what I have there is too hard coded to a specific instance of a query, not the queries as a whole/type.

*Also, note. You don't have to do anything with parsing in this question, like parsing the path. Just assume whatever structure simplifies / gets rid of string parsing for all intents and purposes.*

Typically, instead of using types, I would do "runtime type checking" to verify the query had the appropriate characteristics. But I am really curious to see if it's possible to do this purely with types somehow.